# Cannot use CreateObject from VB scripts on IIS Windows 7 64Bits

Tags: iis, vbscript, asp-classic

When I try to create a COM object in asp vb script on a Windows 7 (64 bit) machine, I always get the following error:

```
    Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01ad'
    ActiveX component can't create object
    /test/test.asp, line 7
```

I have created DLL file like [this tutorial](http://www.dmxzone.com/forum/topic/34326/)

it used to work on windows 7 32 bits.
Is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have access to your server's IIS mamager you can enable 32 bit applications in your app pool

http://help.webcontrolcenter.com/KB/a1114/how-to-enable-32-bit-application-pool-iis-7-dedicatedvps.aspx

Comment: After I do that, some problem happens with the ODBC driver: ODBC Driver Manager The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application

Comment: So you're connecting to a database with a 64 bit driver.  Enabling 32 bit components seems to disable 32 bit ones.  What database are you using, there could well be a 32 bit alternative?

Comment: I'm am using Intersystems Caché 5.2.0.329.0.. =(

Comment: I've never used Cache I'm afraid, but it would appear that there is a 32 bit ODBC driver available. http://www.intersystems.com/services-support/product-support/cache-odbc-driver-faq/

Comment: Your solution works well! I figure out that some parts of my code uses ODBC connections and it was using 32 bits ODBC, as mentioned here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942976. I configured again on 64 BIT odbc and everything worked well! Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 2):

In Windows 64 a 64-bit process cannot load a 32-bit dll. BUT in VB6 (if you followed the indicated tutorial) you can convert your in process dll COM component into an out of process 32-bit exe COM server. Then you will have no problems in instantiating your component.

Comment: Ok, but how do I do that?

Comment: If you followed the indicated tutorial, do the same but change the kind of project. Instead of compiling a ActiveXDll choose a ActiveX exe.

Comment: Ok, i guess i did it. Now how do I do the step 7? 7- We need to register our DLL file on our machine. Open the MS-DOS command line window
and change the directory to where you saved the dll. Now type the following: 
regsvr32 myConnectionString.dll
you will get a conformation window with successful registration…. we are done!

Comment: I have a myConnectionString.exe

Comment: @UderMoreira: congratulations. Now time to register: `myConnectionString.exe /regserver`. See [How To Register and Unregister an Out-of-Process COM Component (ActiveX EXE)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/297279)